# GCC 4.5.2 Linker gots Problem while using Exceptions (C++)

Tags: c++, exception, inheritance, gcc, webserver

I try to write a webserver. As far as I am, it works quiet good with Windows. But I want to make it also Unix compatible. And I think there has to be a problem with the heredity f the exception class.
For better understanding, just the important parts:

server.cpp

```
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>

#ifdef __unix__
    #include "UnixSocket.h"
#elif __WIN32__ || _MSC_VER
    #include "WinSocket.h"
#endif

#include "HTTPParser.h"

int main(void) {
    try {
        socket->socketInit(PORT);
    }
    catch (exception &e) {
        cout << endl << "Exception: " << e.what() << endl;
        socket->cleanAll();
    }
return 0
}
```

NetInterface.h

```
class NetInterface : public exception {

private:

public:
    virtual void socketInit(const char *port) = 0;
    virtual void cleanAll(void) = 0;
    virtual void cleanPersCon(void) = 0;
    virtual char *akzeptieren(void) = 0;
    virtual void empfangen(void) = 0;
    virtual void senden(void) = 0;
    virtual void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa) = 0;
    virtual string getIncoming(void) = 0;
    virtual void setOutcoming(string s) = 0;

    virtual ~NetInterface() throw() {};
```

};

UnixSocket.h

```
class UnixSocket : virtual public NetInterface { 
private: 
    [...]
public:
    UnixSocket(void);
//kill socket connections
    void cleanAll(void);
    void cleanPersCon(void);
//SysCalls
    void socketInit(const char *port);
    char *akzeptieren(void);
    void empfangen(void);
    void senden(void);
//Getter and Setter
    string getIncoming(void);
    void setOutcoming(string s);

    virtual ~UnixSocket() throw() {};
};
```

HTTPParser.h

```
class HTTPParser : public exception {
private:
    [...]

public:
    HTTPParser(NetInterface *_socket, string _path);
    void parsePacket(void);

    virtual ~HTTPParser() throw() {};
};
```

There you can se a short summary of the class declarations.
But now the gcc tells me something like this:

```
/tmp/cc8DNmKI.o:(.rodata._ZTV10HTTPParser[vtable for HTTPParser]+0x10): undefined reference to `std::exception::what() const'
/tmp/cc8DNmKI.o:(.rodata._ZTV10UnixSocket[vtable for UnixSocket]+0x14): undefined reference to `std::exception::what() const'
/tmp/cc8DNmKI.o:(.rodata._ZTV10UnixSocket[vtable for UnixSocket]+0x78): undefined reference to `std::exception::what() const'
/tmp/cc8DNmKI.o:(.rodata._ZTV12NetInterface[vtable for NetInterface]+0x10): undefined reference to `std::exception::what() const'
/tmp/cc8DNmKI.o:(.rodata._ZTV12NetInterface[vtable for NetInterface]+0x14): undefined reference to `__cxa_pure_virtual'
/tmp/cc8DNmKI.o:(.rodata._ZTV12NetInterface[vtable for NetInterface]+0x18): undefined reference to `__cxa_pure_virtual'
/tmp/cc8DNmKI.o:(.rodata._ZTV12NetInterface[vtable for NetInterface]+0x1c): undefined reference to `__cxa_pure_virtual'
/tmp/cc8DNmKI.o:(.rodata._ZTV12NetInterface[vtable for NetInterface]+0x20): undefined reference to `__cxa_pure_virtual'
/tmp/cc8DNmKI.o:(.rodata._ZTV12NetInterface[vtable for NetInterface]+0x24): undefined reference to `__cxa_pure_virtual'
/tmp/cc8DNmKI.o:(.rodata._ZTV12NetInterface[vtable for NetInterface]+0x28): more undefined references to `__cxa_pure_virtual' follow
/tmp/cc8DNmKI.o:(.rodata._ZTVSt16invalid_argument[vtable for std::invalid_argument]+0x10): undefined reference to `std::logic_error::what() const'
/tmp/cc8DNmKI.o:(.rodata._ZTVSt12domain_error[vtable for std::domain_error]+0x10): undefined reference to `std::logic_error::what() const'
/tmp/cc8DNmKI.o:(.rodata._ZTI10HTTPParser[typeinfo for HTTPParser]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
/tmp/cc8DNmKI.o:(.rodata._ZTI10HTTPParser[typeinfo for HTTPParser]+0x8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for std::exception'
/tmp/cc8DNmKI.o:(.rodata._ZTI10UnixSocket[typeinfo for UnixSocket]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info'
/tmp/cc8DNmKI.o:(.rodata._ZTI10UnixSocket[typeinfo for UnixSocket]+0x18): undefined reference to `typeinfo for std::exception'
/tmp/cc8DNmKI.o:(.rodata._ZTI12NetInterface[typeinfo for NetInterface]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
/tmp/cc8DNmKI.o:(.rodata._ZTI12NetInterface[typeinfo for NetInterface]+0x8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for std::exception'
/tmp/cc8DNmKI.o:(.rodata._ZTISt16invalid_argument[typeinfo for std::invalid_argument]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
/tmp/cc8DNmKI.o:(.rodata._ZTISt16invalid_argument[typeinfo for std::invalid_argument]+0x8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for std::logic_error'
/tmp/cc8DNmKI.o:(.rodata._ZTISt12domain_error[typeinfo for std::domain_error]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
/tmp/cc8DNmKI.o:(.rodata._ZTISt12domain_error[typeinfo for std::domain_error]+0x8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for std::logic_error'
/tmp/cc8DNmKI.o:(.eh_frame+0xeb): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and even more....

Comment: What was the command line you used to link the objects?

Comment: Might have to `#include <exception>` and also do `-lstdc++` to link the library.

Comment: Compiling with `g++` and not `gcc`?

Comment: yeah, I missed the -lstdc++...shame on me...thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Judging from `undefined reference to __gxx_personality_v0` linker message it looks like you are linking with `gcc`. You need to link C++ applications with `g++`. Or link with `gcc` and add `-lstdc++` to the linker command line.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't showing the relevant code and compiler invocation, but know that `std::exception` has an unimplemented virtual member function `what()` that you're expected to override, so don't go throwing naked `std::exception`s if you want to call`what()`.

Any of the derived, specific exceptions in `<stdexcept>` will implement `what()` and allow you to store a message when you're constructing the exception object.

Comment: The fact that there is `undefined reference to __gxx_personality_v0` means c++ run-time is not linked in.