# Solaris SunStudio 12.4 Standard Library Linking Issue

Tags: c++, linker, boost-asio, solaris-10, solaris-studio

I'm trying to compile a sample from boost-asio on Solaris-10 using SunStudio 12.4. Compiling with GCC 4.9.2 works, but down the line I will be required to support both compilers, so just switching is not an option.

**CC -V output:** `CC: Sun C++ 5.13 SunOS_sparc 2014/10/20`

**Compilation Line:** (for each cpp file)

`CC -m32 -std=c++11 -I./asio-1.10.6/include -I./boost/include/boost-1_58 -c *.cpp -o *.o`

**Linker Line:** (note that *.o is actually a list of all the object files previously generated)

`CC -m32 -L./boost/sparc/sun/release32/lib *.o -o httpServer -lCrun -lCstd -lxnet -lboost_system`

**The Problem:**

I get a bunch of unresolved symbols for standard library stuff (like string, ios_base, locale, etc.). I posted the linker errors [here](http://textuploader.com/x269).

I strongly suspect that this is related to the use of `-std=c++11`.  I included this option because of a compilation issue with `iterator_traits`. Even though `iterator_traits` is not a C++11 feature, for some reason SunStudio can't compile it unless it is compiling in c++11 mode. The error regarding `iterator_traits`:

`Error: iterator_traits is not a member of std.`

The code causing this compile failure is in boost `boost/detail/iterator.hpp`. Code follows.

```
// (C) Copyright David Abrahams 2002.
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See
// accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at
// http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)

#ifndef ITERATOR_DWA122600_HPP_
#define ITERATOR_DWA122600_HPP_

// This header is obsolete and will be deprecated.

#include <iterator>

namespace boost
{

namespace detail
{

using std::iterator_traits;
using std::distance;

} // namespace detail

} // namespace boost

#endif // ITERATOR_DWA122600_HPP_
```

Other things which include and use this header generate errors like `Error: iterator_traits is not a member of boost::detail`, and then other syntax errors because now it thinks all the following code is invalid.

**Other Things I've Tried:**

- Adding -lC before -lCrun (the linker can't find that library)
- Adding -lc (similar issue).
- Checked in the SUNWspro/libs directory and found that libCrun.so and libCstd.so both exist.
- Putting -lCstd before -lCrun

**Other (Less Relevant) Information:**

- SPARC
- the asio sample in question is the httpServer (I believe it's under the server directory in examples)

Comment: I deleted my answer because I think I was wrong. Maybe I glossed over your linker errors before.

Comment: Try adding -lstdc++ to your compiler args.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire the linker can't find the sdtc++ library. Also in a previous comment you suggested adding -lm. I tried that as well, and although the linker can find it, it makes no difference.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37069_01/html/E37071/gndfg.html - It's definitely an issue with simply failing to link to the standard library somehow.

Comment: If you just just your linked compiler errors as search terms you'll come across dozens of posts like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038258/gcc-4-5-2-linker-gots-problem-while-using-exceptions-c all pointing to the source issue. According to do the docs in C++11 mode, it's simply using the standard library provided by g++ 4.8.2. Search your file system and "obviously where it should be" paths trying to find this to see if it's even on your system.

Comment: Instead of `-std=c++11`, did you try `-library=stdcxx4` (or `-library=stlport4`)? Those are the recommended modes for use with boost. Note that all those flags need to be exactly the same when compiling and linking (and drop `-lCrun` and `-lCstd`).

Comment: @MarcGlisse Yes I tried stlport4 and was able to compile, but upon running immediately seg faults.  In the end, we've decided to go another route, but I think that I could have figured this out with more effort. Should I keep the question for other viewers, or delete it?

Comment: @maria I'm not sure what you should do, since you're abandoning the question. I'd suggest only for the sake of avoiding getting flagged for a post bad to just leave the question alone rather than deleting it. This site has a silly system where if you start deleting your own posts, it suspects you of being a creator of low quality stuff and will eventually ban. Did you try specifying std=... on both your compile and linker phase commands?

Comment: @TechnikEmpire We decided to abandon it before I got to it, unfortunately. If I ever do try this I'll let the community know. I do suspect that that would have solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From The Docs:](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37069_01/html/E37071/gndfg.html)

> In C++ 11 mode, the CC compiler uses the g++ ABI and a version of the
>   g++ runtime library that is supplied with Oracle Solaris Studio. For
>   this release, version 4.8.2 of the g++ runtime library is used.
>
> An ABI describes the low-level details in the generated object code.
>   Modules that use different ABIs cannot successfully be linked together
>   into a program. **This means that you must use C++11 mode on all
>   modules in your program, or none of them**.

So with that said, you must specify "--std=c++11" to the linker phase too. You're not doing this presently.

Comment: But iterator_traits isn't even a C++11 feature, is it? I thought it was C++03, so I'm really confused as to why it can't compile it without setting std to c++11. I will look into posting code tomorrow.

Comment: It's both. I need std=c++11 to compile, but when I compile with c++11 on I can't link. Interesting about the fact that the compiler only supports x86 architectures.

Comment: Ah! Okay, that's really good info. Thanks for all your effort.